# Screen Tints Blue when playing Team Fortress 2 on OSX

Tags: technical-issues, team-fortress-2, macos

Ever since I downloaded tf2 the screen is tinted blue whenever I launch it. I'm on a Macbook Pro 13" early 2011. The same problem has happened to a friend of mine who also has an MBP, but it doesn't happen on an iMac I have. I've narrowed it down to tf2 changing the color profile.

Its not just tf2, all the source games do it, Half Life 2, Garry's Mod, Counter Strike etc. If I go into system prefs and click on displays it fixes itself. This is really annoying to fix manually every time I launch tf2, so if anyone else has figured out how to fix this, I would appreciate them sharing the solution. Thanks.

My specs:

- OSX 10.9.2
- 2.3 GHz Intel Core i5
- 4 GB 1333 MHz DDR3
- Intel HD Graphics 3000 384 MB
- 13-inch Macbook Pro Early 2011

Answer (score 1):

I just experienced the same thing when I was playing around with Screen Sharing (from A I looked at B, and when I tried to connect from B to A, A's screen suddenly got a blue tint). Changing resolution back and forth a couple of times fixed it.

This was also on a MBP 13", bought in april 2012.

Comment: I actually talked to some valve developers and they say that it's a problem with pet window gama in osx. Changing the color profile also works.